# Fonts not appearing hen uploaded to Bluehost

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, display

I recently uploaded my code to bluhost, to create my portfolio website. However, while the fonts were appearing on my computer, they do not display when I load the website (through the host bluehost).

Here is my CSS code. Is the problem trough CSS or bluehost?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: playfair-italic;
    src: url(fonts/playfair-display/PlayfairDisplay-Italic.otf);   
}
@font-face {
    font-family: playfair-regular;
        src: url(fonts/playfair-display/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: playfair-sc;
        src: url(fonts/playfair-display/PlayfairDisplaySC-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face { 
font-family: opensans-regular;
    src: url(fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face { 
font-family: opensans-semibolditalic;
    src: url(fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf);
}

@font-face { 
font-family: opensans-semibold;
    src: url(fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add './' before each url to convert them to relative paths.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: playfair-italic;
    src: url(./fonts/playfair-display/PlayfairDisplay-Italic.otf);   
}
@font-face {
    font-family: playfair-regular;
        src: url(./fonts/playfair-display/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: playfair-sc;
        src: url(./fonts/playfair-display/PlayfairDisplaySC-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face { 
font-family: opensans-regular;
    src: url(./fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face { 
font-family: opensans-semibolditalic;
    src: url(./fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf);
}

@font-face { 
font-family: opensans-semibold;
    src: url(./fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are both Google Fonts you probably want to use a `script` tag to pull the font files in from Google's CDN instead of embedding them into the project and serving them from your site.

In the `<head>` of your HTML file add this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,600i|Playfair+Display+SC|Playfair+Display:400,400i" rel="stylesheet">
```

And to use the fonts in your CSS files, use these rules:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;

//font-weight and font-style will define the rest
font-weight: 400; // This is the regular weight
font-weight: 600; // This is the bold weight

font-style: italic; // The default is regular
```